# getEditableText() abnormal behavior with EditText on different devices

Tags: android

`getEditableText()` behave differently with each device. I have tested it with around API level 19 to 28, on some API `getEditableText()` only call once when the first time the focus comes on EditText. and other devices `getEditableText()` call each time whenever focus goes on it.

I got an issue on API 20 and 28.
`getEdiatbleText()` getting call each time whenever you type something on EditText.

I am expecting `getEditableText` should not call each time.

Comment: why don't you use getText().toString for getting the edit text string ?

Comment: @Abhishek I am not talking about manual calling of getText() or getEditableText(). getEditableText() call itself automatically